# Fade in of an input textbox

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm trying to fade in a textbox via CSS keyframes:

```
.otherAnim{
        animation-delay:11s;
        animation-duration:2s;
        animation-iteration-count:1;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    } 
@keyframes Appear{
    from {opacity:0;}
    to {opacity:1;}
}
```

```
<div class="col" style="width:30%;height:100%">
    <h2>some text</h2>
    <h2 class="otherAnim" style="animation-name:Appear;opacity:0;">some text: </h2>
    <input type="text" id=myInput class="otherAnim inputSoFar" style="animation-name:Appear;float:left;height:45px;opacity:0;">
</div>
```

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/w3m041b3/) works on JSFiddle, but not in my local view of the page (Chrome 57). The weird thing for me is that if I inspect the element, the otherAnim class has dissapeared. This doesn't happen in JSFiddle.  I'm using w3.css, but it still works if I load it as a external resource in JSFiddle.

What am I possibly missing ?

Comment: It could be a ton of things, but ultimately we're just taking guesses if you can't replicate the issue for us. Can you copy and paste the exact code that isn't working, or is that what you did here? An `input` doesn't need to be closed (remove `</input>`), btw, but that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: I mean copy and paste everything as it is with your best description of context where necessary. And is the CSS just on the page like that or in an external file?

Comment: if that's your actual page, at a minimum, your CSS needs to be in a `<style>` tag, and your page should have a `doctype`. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evwaww you need a bunch of other stuff, but those things should make it work.

Comment: Thanks, I found the bug. A class-replacing script was the culprit. Is there anyway I could have found out that the script had replaced the class by inspecting it with chrome?  As you can see I'm just starting in this technologies.

Comment: Yeah, do you know how to use the dev tools? Inspect the element and look at the classes applied and you can see what CSS is applied. If something killed the class that was doing this animation, you should either not see the animation CSS in dev tools, or it will be crossed out or something if it was overwritten.

Comment: I disrupted the animation via JS by doing .setAttribute("class","inputSoFar");  and I couldn't find a trace of this in the dev tools. I was wondering if there's a place there where I could have seen that this had changed the original classes of the element.

Comment: You wouldn't see that javascript replaced it the CSS per se (like it won't say "class replaced with javascript" or anything), you'd just notice upon inspecting that the styles don't look like you expected or that the `class` attribute doesn't list the class(es) you expected.

Comment: I know this isn't supposed to occur here, but thanks for your help!

Comment: no problem, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the `animation-name` property in inline style. You have to put it in the style tag or a linked css file.